# question about span and basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question from homework (I'm not sure if my solution is correct):

> Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$ and let $W$ be subspace of $V$.
>
> Let $u$ and $v$ be vectors in $V$.
>
> $u,v \notin W$ but $v+2u \in W$
>
> is $span(W \cup \{u, v\})$ is also subspace of $V$?
>
> If it is, give a possible basis.

It seems that  $span(W \cup \{u, v\})$ is subspace of V because for every $t_1, t_2 \in span(W \cup \{u, v\})$ and $a \in \mathbb{F}$:

- $0\in span(W \cup \{u, v\})$
- $t_1 +  t_2\in span(W \cup \{u, v\})$
- $a \cdot t_1\in span(W \cup \{u, v\})$

Now, the basis can be $W \cup \{u\}$ or $W \cup \{v\}$ because it's enough to have either $u$ or $v$ in the union because I know that $v+2u \in W$.

But $W$ can be linearly dependent, and basis should be set of linearly independent vectors.
So is it correct to say that the basis is $B \cup \{u\}$ or $B \cup \{v\}$ when $B$ is basis of $W$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First notice that for all **subset** $S$ of $V$ we have
$$\operatorname{span }S$$
is a subspace of $V$ since by definition it's the smallest subspace of $V$ containing $S$.

For the second question,  the two vectors $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent, otherwise and WLOG we assume that 
$$u=\alpha v$$
and then
$$v+2u=(1+2\alpha)v\in W\Rightarrow  v\in W\quad\text{which's a contradiction}$$

and since $v+2u\in W$ then there's $w\in W$ such that $v=w-2u$ hence $B\cup\{u\}$ is a basis of $\operatorname{span }(W\cup\{u,v\})$ where $B$ is a basis of $W$.